# Getting the Name of a Func<TSource, TKey> Generic Type Parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I'm using a Func as an argument for a method to be used in a GroupBy operation in a Linq statement. TSource being IFoo and TKey being a property of IFoo such as IFoo.Number, making my Func parameter looking like:

```
foo => foo.Number
```

So far so good. However, now I'm trying to get a string representation of TKey or rather, I'm trying the coax the string "Number" from the Func<> parameter.

Can it be done and if so, how? Thanking you all in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't with a Func, you need a parameter  of type `Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>`

and work on Expression's Body.

When you need the func, just compile the expression.

To get name from expression :
[Retrieving Property name from lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression)